# How to get the nearby user names in android using firebase as database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have added the screenshot of my firebase db below.I am using geofire to get the nearby users location lat/lng that is stored in electriciansAvailable.I have used adapter to show list of nearby users in the ui and I am able to show the keys stored in electriciansAvailable.

But I do not want to show the keys,but instead want to show the names of the user(eg:-san@gmail.com).I am stuck with this since a long time,please can someone tell me how to show the names of the nearby usernames in a list form?

Below I have attached my screenshot and code.It updates electricians value to true in db but the electricianname shows blank in listview.Below i have uploaded the screenshot and code.

```js
fun getElectriciansAround(){
        getElectriciansArounStarted = true
        val customerId: String = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
        val driversLocation:DatabaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("electricianAvailable")
        val geofire:GeoFire= GeoFire(driversLocation)
        val geoQuery:GeoQuery = geofire.queryAtLocation(GeoLocation(mLastLocation.latitude,mLastLocation.longitude), 10000.0)

        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(object : GeoQueryEventListener{

            override fun onKeyEntered(key: String?, location: GeoLocation?) {
                val electricianRef:DatabaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users").child("Electricians").child(key!!)



                driversLocation.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener{
                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.childrenCount>0){
                            for(i in 0 until dataSnapshot.childrenCount){
                                electricianRef.child(customerId).setValue(true)
                                getDriverName("Electricians",key!!)
                                electricianNames= arrayOf(mElectricianName)
                                val adapter= ArrayAdapter(this@CustomerElectricianHome, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, electricianNames)
                                mListViewElectricians.adapter=adapter
                            }
                        }
                    }

                })
 Run code snippet
```

```js
var mElectricianName:String=""

    private fun getDriverName(ElectricianName: String, key: String) {
        val mDriverNameDb:DatabaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users").child(ElectricianName).child(key)
        mDriverNameDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    val map:Map<*,*> = dataSnapshot.value as Map<*,*>
                    if(map["name"]!=null){
                        mElectricianName= map["name"].toString()
                    }

                }
            }

        })



    }
```

[[enter image description here][image: 1]]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to look up the additional user data with an extra read from the Firebase Realtime Database from inside the `GeoQueryEventListener.onKeyEntered` method.

Something like:

```
geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Key %s entered the search area at [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
        DatabaseReference electriciansRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/Electricians");
        electriciansRef.child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                System.out.println(String.format("Electrician name: %s", name));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        })
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
        System.err.println("There was an error with this query: " + error);
    }
});
```

Or in Kotlin:

```
geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(object:GeoQueryEventListener() {
  fun onKeyEntered(key:String, location:GeoLocation) {
    println(String.format("Key %s entered the search area at [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude))
    val electriciansRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/Electricians")
    electriciansRef.child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object:ValueEventListener() {
      fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot:DataSnapshot) {
        val name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String::class.java)
        println(String.format("Electrician name: %s", name))
      }
      fun onCancelled(databaseError:DatabaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException()
      }
    })
  }

  ...

  fun onGeoQueryError(error:DatabaseError) {
    System.err.println("There was an error with this query: " + error)
  }
})
```

Comment: Don't post additional problems as an answer. Instead, click the edit link under your question and add the information there. Please also limit the scope of your question and be explicit about what doesn't work. Finally: be sure to copy the code from my answer correct, as you're not attaching a listener to `electricianRef` as far as I can see.

Comment: i added the listener in another function getDriverName() above.is it right?

Comment: If you use my exact code, it should log the electrician's name when they're in range of the geoquery. Your code is quite different in places, and I can't say if that is correct.

Comment: i am new to android so I might have messed up the code.It works now!!thanks loads!!